# I updated this question

Tags: discussion, question-quality, specific-question

[Where can I find a good tutorial for installing bcache?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62501/where-can-i-find-a-good-tutorial-for-installing-bcache)

I've heard that bcache is now part of the standard linux instalation.

That means I can order a server with 2HDD and 2SDD and uses the SDD to cache the HDD.

I am looking for a tutorial to do so
Should the question be reopened?

Answer (score 5):

We generally delete answers that just contain a link to another site with no other information. As explained on [the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer), if the link breaks, the answer is now useless. Furthermore, most people's workflow is to Google for their problem, which means they've probably already seen that page in their search results; they really don't need to click another result and find our site, only to discover that it just links back to the pages they've already seen

In your case, you're actually requesting answers of that form, which is why the question isn't a good fit for Stack Exchange. Finding pages on a given topic is what search engines are good at. There's no reason to try and manually compile a list, particularly since it will fall out of date over time